# How to stop navigation while getting error message in validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have check the validation while Onblur.
When I click submit button how can check whether the fields get error message or not?
The form id is 'personal'.
I have use the below code for validation while onblur.

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
    jQuery('input').keypress(function( e ) {
        if(e.which === 32) 
            return false;
    });
    jQuery('#personal').validate({
        onkeyup: false,
        rules: {
            Fname: {
                // customRule: true,
                required: true,
                minlength: 3 // for demo
            },
            Uname: {
                // customRule: true,
                required: true,
                minlength: 6 // for demo
            },

            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                minlength: 6 // for demo
            }, 
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            },
            confirmpassword: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#password1"
            }          
        }
    });

    jQuery('#personal').validate({        
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            if (jQuery('#personal').valid()) {
                //form.submit(); // commented out for demo
                alert('submitted'); // for demo
                return false; // for demo
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            jQuery('#personal').valid(); // force validation on first form when this form has error
            error.insertAfter(element); // default placement
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In you submit function you can check:

```
if (!$('#personal').valid()) {
  return;
}
```

The `valid()` method returns true or false. It is available with `validate`.

Comment: You may consider upvoting my answer or accepting it if it has helped you solve your problem. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

when validation fails the `jquery.validate() methods  adds  an error class to each form element whose validation is unsuccessful.So you simply check whether the class`"error"` is present or not.